# Javers querybuilder for anyDomainObject with commit property filter not working

Tags: javers

The Javers JQL to get all domain objects returns empty list.

I've written a wrapper rest api and exposed the Javers commit and getAllShadows  api's as below.

```
@PutMapping("/commit")
public <T> CommitEntity<T> commit(@RequestBody CommitEntity<T> committedObject);

@GetMapping("/getEntityShadows")
public List<EntityShadow> getEntityShadows(@RequestParam(name = "entityId") String entityId);
```

Now when I use the commit API(above), I'm able to commit my domain object to the repository (mongo)

Sample below:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c5f6fb51ebaa93b96edadc8"),
"commitMetadata" : {
    "author" : "UserFName UserLname",
    "properties" : [ 
        {
            "key" : "entityId",
            "value" : "user001/US"
        }
    ],
    "commitDate" : "2019-02-09T16:26:29.543",
    "commitDateInstant" : "2019-02-10T00:26:29.543Z",
    "id" : NumberLong(8440229536252376064)
},
"globalId" : {
    "valueObject" : "org.javers.core.graph.LiveGraphFactory$MapWrapper"
},
"state" : {
    "map" : {
        "userId" : {
            "id" : "user001",
            "locale" : "US"
        },
        "createdDate" : "2019-02-08T22:16:58",
        "Name" : "User Fname",
        "address" : {
            "state" : "CA",
            "country" : "US"
        },
        "authorName" : "UserFName UserLname",
        "lastModifiedBy" : "2019-02-09T16:26:29"
    }
},
"changedProperties" : [ 
    "map"
],
"type" : "INITIAL",
"version" : NumberLong(1),
"globalId_key" : "org.javers.core.graph.LiveGraphFactory$MapWrapper/"
```

}

Now when I try to get all shadows as below, I get back an empty List. I expected to get all the shadows from the repo.

```
JqlQuery jqlQuery = QueryBuilder.anyDomainObject().withCommitProperty("entityId", "user001/US").build();
List<Shadow<Object>> shadows = javers.findShadows(jqlQuery);
```

Am I missing anything here?

I tried to just get the shadows with any filter like below, still got back an empty list

```
JqlQuery jqlQuery = QueryBuilder.anyDomainObject().build();
List<Shadow<Object>> shadows = javers.findShadows(jqlQuery);
```

Comment: Looks like you are committing Maps instead of your domain objects. Technically, you can do this, but it's not recommended.

Comment: @BartekWalacik Thanks for commenting. I agree it is being committed as a Map. What I'm trying to do is to create a micro service where multiple apps can commit their objects using the API (public <T> CommitEntity<T> commit(@RequestBody CommitEntity<T> committedObject);). Now if a T type object is being committed,, it automatically commits as a Map. Is there any other way of committing this, so that the domain object is committed as it is (and not as a map).

Comment: @BartekWalacik Sharing the CommitEntity POJO for making it clearer. public class CommitEntity<T> {
 private T commitObj;
 private String authorName;
 private Map<String, String> commitProperties;
 private String entityId;
}

Comment: javers is strongly typed and it expects that you commit your concrete domain objects, <T> means anything

Comment: so you cant commit via REST, plug javers directly in every app that needs it